# Trying to display biggest number in array while displaying the corresponding title using a void function. I'm new to C++

Tags: c++

Edit: I changed a little bit of it but here's a photo of the code since I can't put it here https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy1i2.png

The "getHighestGraphics" function was my attempt to display the biggest number corresponding to the title. I have two strings; one for the GraphicsScore and the other for the Titles.

```
void getHighestGraphics(string GraphicScore, string TitlesArray) 
{
    for (int count = 1; count < 5; count++)
    {
        if (GraphicScore[0] < GraphicScore[count])
            GraphicScore[0] = GraphicScore[count];
        
        cout << endl << "The highest rated graphics game is " << GraphicScore[0] << " with a score of "
             << TitlesArray[count] << endl;
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: you are passing in 2 strings, i think you want to pass in arrays or vectors of strings

Comment: also you are comparing numbers in strings, this wont work as you expect

Comment: Tip:`const std::string&` to avoid copies.

Comment: Hint: `std::string x = "abc"` means that `x[0]` is just the letter `'a`'. You probably mean `std::vector<string>` and using tools like `std::sort`.

Comment: store your scores in a std::vector<std::uint64_t> (int can be a bit too small, and no need to store values in a string type) and use std::sort to sort them by value. The highest score will be the first value in your vector.

Comment: Better to use a `struct` or `std::pair` or `std::unordered_map` instead of tracking two arrays simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments mention you are passing two string. If these are standard strings what you are doing does not makes much sense since you can think of std::string more or less as char array there fore your function is not doing what you are trying to do.
You can use map for this if each title is different (which I presume it must be.)

Here is a fully working example as requested by @Spencer:

```
bool getHighestGraphics( const std::map<std::string, int>& titles, std::pair<std::string, int> &result) 
{
    int max_score = 0;
    int index = -1;
    int counter = 0;
    for ( auto title : titles)
    {
        if (max_score < title.second){
            max_score = title.second;
            index = counter;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    if (max_score > 0 && index > -1){
        auto it = titles.begin();
        std::advance(it, index);            
        result.first = it->first;
        result.second = max_score;
        return true;            
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> titles;
    titles["game0"] = 4;
    titles["game1"] = 1;
    titles["game2"] = 3;
    titles["game3"] = 2;
    titles["game4"] = 5;
    titles["game5"] = 7;
    titles["game6"] = 6;
    titles["game7"] = 10;
    titles["game8"] = 8;
    titles["game9"] = 9;
    
    std::pair<std::string, int> result;
    
    if (getHighestGraphics(titles, result))
    {
        std::cout << "The highest rated graphics game is: " << result.second << " " << result.first << std::endl;
    }
    else std::cout <<"None found" << std::endl;            
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing the map by value?

Comment: @sweenish no reason in particular, I just wrote it like that. 
I have edit it so it is not by value. 
For anyone else reading: Not passing it by value will make it faster because there is no data copied. I also made it const so the data is not changed when it comes back from the function.

Comment: Instead of writing to `cout` in the function, return something from `getHighestGraphics`  into the calling function.  You can then give us a sample `main` which calls the function and writes the result to `cout`.